# Codeigniter: Url routing seleccionar elemento de menú agrega segmentos a url

Tags: php, codeigniter

En una nueva instalación de codeigniter 3.x tengo un controlador 'interprete_registro.php' con un funcion:

**Config**

config.php

```
$route['interprete-registro'] = 'interprete_registro';
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**Controllers**

interprete_registro.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Interprete_Registro extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('interprete_registro_view');
    }   

}
```

**views**

interprete_registro_view.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Titulo<title>
</head>
<body>
 Bienvenido
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Titulo<title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <nav>
<ul><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('interprete-registro'); ?>">Registrar</a></li></ul>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Resultado**
No se puede abrir url.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**.htacces**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /SILSCHS/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poner con letra inicial mayúscula el nombre del archivo controlador porque dependiendo del servidor que estés usando va a diferenciar las mayúsculas de minúsculas.

Controllers

*Interprete_registro.php*:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class **Interprete_registro** extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('interprete_registro_view');
    }   

}
```

Comment: Angel, cambie Interprete_registro.php y Interprete_registro de controlador. ya no funciona